# to employ charts(written in python using matplolib) in html file

Tags: python, django, linux, matplotlib, ubuntu-10.04

I have created app using django which searches the keywords entered by the user in 10 xml documents and maintains the frequency count of those words for each file. The results are returned to the user in the form of expandable hyperlinked list of filenames and the charts. My html code:

```
<html>
 <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
             position: absolute;
             top:   5px;
             left:  200px;      
           }    
        form #Edit1 { 
                     position: absolute;
                     top:    37px; 
                     left:   410px; 
                    }
        form #Edit2 { 
                     position: absolute; 
                     top:    37px; 
                     left:   840px; 
                    }
       </style>
       <font size="4" face="arial" color="#0000FF">
       <h1>XML Search</h1>
       </font>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <Form Action ="/search/" Method ="POST">
       <div id="Edit1">
            <INPUT TYPE = 'VARCHAR'  name ='word' VALUE ="" size = "50">
       </div>
       <div id="Edit2">
            <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" VALUE = "Search">
       </div>
       <br/>
       <hr/>
       {% csrf_token %}
       </FORM>
       {% if list1 %}
          <input type="text" name="word" value="{{ word }}" />
          <ul> 
             {% for l in list1 %}
                  <li><a href="{{STATIC_URL}}static/{{l.file_name}}">{{l.file_name}}</a>, {{l.frequency_count}}</li>
             {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          <br/>     
     # -- charts to be employed -- #
       {% endif %}
</html>
```

this html page is redirected from views.py file. Now, I want to write the code for charts  using matplotlib in this html code. As the code to create charts using the mentioned library is written in python, so how can I write this python code in the above html file or if there is any other way out, so please tell?

Note:
I have made use of google charts and that are working perfectly fine but I want to make this app internet independent, so please do not suggest me google charts.

Please Help , I'm new to charts and django.

Comment: hey can no one help me at this ?

Answer (score 1):

The [matplotlib cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Django) has an [entry](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Django) on using matplotlib with django.

It boils down to the following:

- In urls.py you add an entry for a png with a link to a new view.
- In your new view you create a HttpResponse with content_type image/png
- Using matplotlib you write a figure as png to the aforementioned HttpResponse

A straight copy/paste from the cookbook should get you going.

Perhaps you can break the problem into bite size pieces to avoid learning three things at once:

1. Add a static .png to your page
2. Add a dynamic .png to your page via urls.py and a new view
3. Create a figure in Matplotlib (offline)
4. Put the matplotlib figure from step 3 into the dynamic image from step 2